# Facebook pixel нарушает валидацию страницы

Tags: html, facebook, валидация, теги

Проверяю сайт через [валидатор W3 validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) и получаю такую ошибку

> Error: A link element must not appear as a descendant of a body
>   element unless the link element has an itemprop attribute or has a rel
>   attribute whose value contains dns-prefetch, pingback, preconnect,
>   prefetch, preload, prerender, or stylesheet.

В это виноват facebook pixel, а именно скрипт, подключенный в теге `head`.

```
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="ru-RU">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="#">
<link rel="pingback" href="#">
<title></title>
            <!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
            <script>
            !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
            n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
            n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
            t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
            document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
                                fbq('init', '501918696809596');

            fbq('track', 'PageView');
            </script>
            <noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
            src="#"
            /></noscript>
            <!-- DO NOT MODIFY -->
            <!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->            
<!-- All in One SEO Pack 2.3.15.3 by Michael Torbert of Semper Fi Web Design[297,313] -->
<link rel="author" href="#" />
<link rel="canonical" href="#" />
<!-- /all in one seo pack -->
```

При отключении - ошибка исчезает. Можно ли как-то этот момент устранить?
В [руководстве](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/952192354843755?helpref=faq_content#addbasecode) четко сказано:

> Вставьте код пикселя Facebook между тегами  и  на своей
>   веб-странице. У вас уже могут быть другие коды между тегами «head»,
>   поэтому просто поместите код пикселя ниже других кодов, но выше тега
>   .

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Единственное, что можно посоветовать — переместить ваши link перед скриптом фейсбука. Это замаскирует проблему (валидатор перестанет выдавать ошибку из вопроса), но тем не менее — фейсбук продолжает нагло нарушать стандарты HTML и этот скрипт отвратителен. Тег img нельзя пихать внутрь тега head.

Comment: Но если вы всё-таки готовы пойти на модификацию скрипта, то предлагаю перенести один лишь noscript внутрь body — это исправит проблему

Comment: @andreymal да, тоже к этому пришел, спасибо. Единственный момент - валидатор ругнулся, что в `img` не хватает атрибута `alt` - я подставил и вуаля - ошибка ушла полностью!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть элегантное решение -  вынести за тег `head` и в тег `img` еще внести атрибут `alt`, тогда у валидатора вопросов не останется

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="ru-RU">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="#">
<link rel="pingback" href="#">
<title></title>
      <!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
      <script>
      !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
      n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
      n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
      t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
      document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
                fbq('init', '501918696809596');

      fbq('track', 'PageView');
      </script>
      <!-- DO NOT MODIFY -->
      <!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->          
<!-- All in One SEO Pack 2.3.15.3 by Michael Torbert of Semper Fi Web Design[297,313] -->
<link rel="author" href="#" />
<link rel="canonical" href="#" />
<!-- /all in one seo pack -->
</head>
<body>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" src="#" alt="facebook-pixel" /></noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Этот скрипт нельзя пихать в head, пихайте его в body

Comment: @andreymal сдается мне, что вы не знаете, что такое facebook pixel. 
ликбез - https://www.facebook.com/business/help/952192354843755?helpref=faq_content#addbasecode
`Вставьте код пикселя Facebook между тегами <head> и </head> на своей веб-странице. У вас уже могут быть другие коды между тегами «head», поэтому просто поместите код пикселя ниже других кодов, но выше тега </head>.`
https://scontent-arn2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t39.2365-6/11409193_1605465096376853_497323941_n.jpg?oh=96eb3c9b546b2562a17e08b576691ed9&oe=5A2FAA3C

Comment: В таком случае это исправить невозможно. Фейсбук нагло нарушает стандарты HTML. Исправляется это только перемещением кода в body, а если этого делать нельзя, значит исправить невозможно.

Comment: Для кода из изменённого ответа валидатор у меня выдаёт 7 ошибок :)

Comment: @andreymal приведите пример в каком-нить фидле.
я же, надеюсь, вы понимаете, что я выложил только верхнюю часть кода

Comment: Ну да, я скопировал этот код в валидатор, дописал `</head><body></body></html>` и получил 7 ошибок. В том числе те, которые указаны в вопросе)

Comment: @andreymal да, сорри - это я тут скопировал старый пример и не вынес `<noscript>` в тег `body`. Сейчас уже все хорошо?

Comment: Сейчас ругается на пустой title. Но это мелочь, всё остальное теперь хорошо :)